# Аутентификация через гугл текст кнопки

Tags: android, google-account

Есть кнопка гугл аутентификации, в разметке выглядит так

```
<com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton

    android:id="@+id/button_googlePlusLogin"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    >
</com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton>
```

У нее стандартный текст "Sign in"
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как поменять текст с Sign in на что то другое? android:text="text" она не принимает.
Еще и текст расположен коряво, хотелось бы его и подвинуть по центру

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
protected void setGooglePlusButtonText(SignInButton signInButton, String buttonText) {
// Найти TextView внутри SignInButton и установите текст
for (int i = 0; i < signInButton.getChildCount(); i++) {
    View v = signInButton.getChildAt(i);

    if (v instanceof TextView) {
        TextView tv = (TextView) v;
        tv.setText(buttonText);
        return;
    }
} }
```

Попробуй так, должно работать

Comment: Решение рабочее, Благодарю! К слову, у signButton всего один child)